# PETL python removing rows

Tags: python, petl

how can I delete rows using petl library?

I have loaded the data using:

```
self.tab = petl.fromcsv(self.filename, delimiter=self.delimiter, encoding=self.source_encoding)
```

Now how can I delete rows in the self.tab with conditions? i think in pandas you can do like df.drop but does petl have?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse engineer your case by using select is not
https://pythonhosted.org/petl/0.11.1/index.html#petl.selectisnot